# Vim, constantly displaying args list

Tags: vim, args, vim-airline

I found that arguments list is more useful than buffers list. With vim-airline plugin you can see all current buffers in the topbar. I wonder if there is a similar plugin or function to always display argument list? It would be useful if it could work together with vim-airline.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is a bad idea. The argument list is frequently used for mass-editing many (hundreds) of files, and those wouldn't fit anywhere in the UI. That's why I'm also no fan of permanently displaying the buffer list. [1]

With tabs, windows, and buffers (and dozens of related commands), Vim has very powerful means to deal with multiple files. Each person's workflow is unique; you need to find your very own, personal one by learning the available commands (the `:help` is very comprehensive), and trying out different approaches.

---

[1] From a functional standpoint, buffer and argument lists actually are very similar. Both can be added to, removed from, and used for mass operations. It's only that the adding to the buffer list is done automatically.

Comment: I was thinking about the workflow similar to http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist But I get your point, that's why probably not many plugins for this task.

Comment: In my personal workflow, I do not have that many files open in buffers. I tend to close thes buffers I do not need anymore. Because of that I like to navigate in the buffers with :bn and :bp and would like to change the order, so that often used files are next to each orther. But it seems that this isn't possible with buffers, only with args. But again vim airline onls shows args.